# Azure Self-Hosted agent behind proxy PublishTestResults wildcard names not matched

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

On azure self-hosted agent behind proxy running on Ubuntu, for task PublishTestResults, it always give below warning and test result files are not published.

> ##[warning]No test result files matching /home/username/agent/_work/1/../functional_testing/reports/**/*.xml
> were found.

But when file names are provided, it can find and upload test results. So

```
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
    testResultsFiles: |
      Testreport_DataState/DataState.xml
      Testreport_TR-11123/TR-11123.xml
      Testreport_TR-11141/TR-11141.xml
      Testreport_TR-11142/TR-11142.xml
    searchFolder: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/../functional_testing/reports'
```

works, but

```
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
    testResultsFiles: '**/*.xml'
    searchFolder: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/../functional_testing/reports'
```

do not.

Agent was configured with proxy url and in *runsvc.sh* proxy url are exported.
What could be the reason for this behavior? Thanks.

Comment: Have you edited your post for brevity or is this the actual path? Because I'm confused as to why you have extra `/` in the path and the point of the `..`

```/home//agent/_work/1/../functional_testing/reports/**/*.xml were found.```

 Try to simplify your path without `..` parent selector.

Eg. $(Pipeline.Workspace)/full/path/functional_testing/reports

Comment: Extra `/ ` in post was because of markup error. And you are right, after simplifying path without `..` , it works. Thank you! You can post this comment as answer.